# xdebug, having problems with profiler output

Tags: php, performance, optimization, xdebug

Right, since watching [Rasmus Lerdorf's talk on PHP performance](http://about.digg.com/blog/rasmus-lerdorf-php-performance) I've been wanting to profile the ERP / Accounting application I am working on, not least because I know there are performance issues with it, profiling should highlight the major problems for me to investigate.

So downloaded `xdebug` and put the following few lines in my `php.ini` file:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/home/me/xdebug/profiles/"
xdebug.ptofiler_enable_trigger=On
```

With this I simply aim my browser as my app with `&XDEBUG_PROFILE` in the query string and the profiling begins. The problem is the output I am viewing with KCacheGrind doesn't include any of the functions from with my application, and no flow between entities.

When the page is executing I copied (in the terminal) the profile file to a separate file, to capture it's state throughout the profile. I loaded each of these separately into KCacheGrind and they all show the full profile of the application, all but the last one?

Can anyone tell me why the full profile isn't being output? Looking at the file sizes of my copied files it appears the first few are rather large, but the last one is significantly smaller, is `xdebug` messing with them after it has been captured?

Many thanks :-)

**EDIT**

Just to help, this is what I see when I open up one of the copied profiles (before the profile has completed), I'm sure there is much more to this.

[image]

And this is what I get from the final profile, no relationships, just a bunch of PHP functions. I want to see all the full profile.

[image]

**EDIT 2**

So here I am constantly running the `ls -als` command, the last list is the cut down version, the previous one is the last `ls` where the file was at it's full size.

[image]

I cannot upload the large file as it's over 3 million lines long, if it helps here is the `xdebug` php info section.

[image]

Comment: you might consider another method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756446/making-php-performance-profiling-predictable/3756929#3756929

Comment: The link seems to be broken, is this video you were referencing? https://vimeo.com/13768954

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, I've actually solved the problem myself, I added this option to my `php.ini` file:

```
xdebug.profiler_append=1
```

This will append the data to the same filename if it exists, therefore I'll need to make sure the filename option is set correctly, but I think that has solved my problem for now.

Thanks to those that answered :-)

Comment: I recommend something like `xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t.%R"` for the filename option. It timestamps the filename, ensuring a unique one is generated for each profiling session and allows you to sort by time. It also includes the request URI which helps you distinguish among traces. (Though I remember something about needing to play with the `register_long_arrays` option before `%R` works in some version of xdebug or another.)